# How to serve static Diazo resources with no cookies?

Tags: cookies, plone, diazo

When using a Diazo theme, the static resources currently require authorization in order to show them. Here is how the static theme is registered:

```
<plone:static directory="static" type="theme" name="projecttheme" />
```

If you strip off the cookies (via varnish in this case) from these resources, you'd get the following errors in the log for each static resource:

```
2013-08-29 18:50:35 DEBUG ImplPython Unauthorized: Your user account does not have 
the required permission.  Access to 'project.css' of (FilesystemResourceDirectory
object at /data/project/eggs/project.theme-1.29-py2.7.egg/project/theme/static/styles)
denied. Your user account, Anonymous User, exists at /acl_users. Access requires
Access_contents_information_Permission, granted to the following roles:
['Contributor', 'Editor', 'Manager', 'Owner', 'Reader', 'Site Administrator']. Your
roles in this context are ['Anonymous'].
```

So, if there is no cookie, there is no auth, then you get permission denied because of the `Access contents information` permission. Is there any way to serve up static Diazo resources without this restriction?